# How to identify whether to use union or overlap in extended entity relationship diagram?

Tags: database-design

How to identify whether to use union or overlap in extended entity relationship diagram? Because both looks more or less the same. In a given case study, how do we exactly figure out we should use union or overlap to classify the classes?

Answer (score 0):

**Union is "Uniting Together in T or V"**

> T{a,b,c} V{x,y,z} T union V returns { a,b,c,x,y,z}

The 'or' tells us that an object is in set T or V.

**Intersection is "Finding Common in T and V**

```
T{a,b,c} V{x,y,z} T Intersection V returns {}
```

The 'and' tells us that it is in T and V at the same time.

Comment: I am asking with regards to extended entity relationship diagram?